# Clear cache related to POST requests in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodemailer

I'm using nodemailer to allow users to contact me via email. After submitting the form data, I'm redirected to my homepage (which is what I want), but if I try to refresh the page I get an alert message that says:

> ```
> Confirm Form Resubmission
> The page that you're looking for used information that you entered. 
> Returning to that page might cause any action you took to be repeated. 
> Do you want to continue?
> ```

I think this has something to do with the user's data being cached, so is there a way around this? I don't want people sending me multiple emails by accident, and I don't want them annoyed with an alert box every time they refresh. Here's my controller function:

```
module.exports.contactMessage = function(req, res) {

    // html message sent to my email
    var output = `
        <p>You have a new contact request</p>
        <h3>Contact Details</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>Name: ${req.body.name + ' ' + req.body.surname}</li>
            <li>Email: ${req.body.email}</li>
        </ul>
        <h3>Message:</h3>
        <p>${req.body.message}</p>
        `;

    var from = req.body.email;
    var to = 'example@example.com';

    // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'smtp.gmail.email',
        service: "Gmail",
        auth: {
            user: 'example@example.com', 
            pass: 'password'  
        },
        tls: {
            rejectUnauthorized:false
        }
    });

    // setup email data with unicode symbols
    let mailOptions = {
        from: from, // sender address
        to: to, // list of receivers
        html: output // html body
    };

    // send mail with defined transport object
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            return console.log(error);
        }
        console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);

        res.render('index', {msg: 'Your message has been sent'});
    });
};
```

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: This page provided a clear explanation and solved my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Usually appending a random integer to the end of the url will cause the browser to reload the page because it does not match exactly what is in cache.

For example, `https://www.google.com?318973187678123` will load the same page as `https://www.google.com` but will force the browser to not load from cache.

Note however, this random integer needs change each reload to work, so generate a new random integer each reload.

Comment: I see now that this is not what you were looking for, but good to know anyways for other redirect types.

Comment: Actually, this is useful to know. But to anyone wondering, I ended up just using express's res.redirect() method